# Implementing horizontal scrollbar with jquery accordion

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

I have a jquery accordion and there is a gridview inside it. Grid view is long and it shows only a part of the gridview. How can I have horizontal scrollbar in accordion-content-active?

**HTML :**

```
<div id="MyAccordion">
     <div class="scroll_auto" >
          <MyApp:GridView ID="Mygv" runat="server" CssClass="Grid">
                ...
          </MyApp:GridView>
     </div>
</div>
```

**CSS :**

```
.scroll_auto {
    overflow: auto;
    height: 150px;
    width: 99%;
    border: 1px solid #CDCDCD;
    padding: 1px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is unclear without the complete code.But try this in your css

```
.scroll_auto {
overflow-x: auto;
overflow-y: hidden;
height: 150px;
width: 99%;
border: 1px solid #CDCDCD;
padding: 1px;
}
```